# Compiling Mame 0.170 on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: compiling, gcc, mame

when trying to compile mame 0.170 I get the following error:

```
m1xalis@m1xalis-HP-Compaq-6830s:~$ cd .mame
m1xalis@m1xalis-HP-Compaq-6830s:~/.mame$ make
GCC 5.2.1 detected
Compiling src/osd/modules/debugger/debugqt.cpp...
../../../../../src/osd/modules/debugger/debugqt.cpp:18:34: fatal error: QtWidget
s/QApplication: No such file or directory
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

compilation terminated.
qtdbg_sdl.make:361: recipe for target        '../../../../linux_gcc/obj/x64/Release/qtdbg_sdl/src/osd/modules/debugger/debugqt.o' failed
make[2]: *** [../../../../linux_gcc/obj/x64/Release/qtdbg_sdl/src/osd/modules/debugger/debugqt.o] Error 1
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'qtdbg_sdl' failed
make[1]: *** [qtdbg_sdl] Error 2
makefile:1025: recipe for target 'linux_x64' failed
make: *** [linux_x64] Error 2
```

This is a new install and upgrade to ubuntu wily. I had previously compiled mame 0.169 on ubuntu trusty tahr using gcc 4.9 (I think). Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I just added the #include <QtWidgets/QApplication> line in the makefile user options and it seems to work now, compiling is in progress.

Answer (score 6):

I found that I needed to add this to the makefile:

```
QT_HOME = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/
```

This was actually on Debian jessie, not Ubuntu.  The directory on your system may or may not be the same.  But it shouldn't be too hard to locate.

Answer (score 0):

I just added the #include  line in the makefile user options and it seems to work now, compiling is in progress.

Answer (score -1):

It Works fine for me, compiling Mame 0.172 on Linux Mint 17.3!

(with qt5-default package installed previously

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

and executing on terminal this:

```
export QT_SELECT=qt5
```

(for Qt5 version as default on system))

Comment: -1 The OP asks for Ubuntu 15.10 not for Mint 17.3